# Discord Bot Python - Changing Bot's nickname

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to get the bot's name to change every time it runs. I've check the discord.py docs but nothing there has been of use and none of them throw up any errors. Any ideas?

Has perms 'admin' and 'change nickname'

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)
bot.remove_command('help')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.user.edit(nick="New Nickname")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Does the bot have permissions to change nicknames?

Comment: Yeah has admin and change nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have the [member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=me#discord.Guild.me) object of your bot to change your nickname as nicknames are done in guild's. Then you must [edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=me#discord.Member.edit) it.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        await guild.me.edit(nick="new nickname")
```